# Google Assistant - Sign in to Strava

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-oauth

Apologies if this is a newbie question but I'm hoping someone can offer some advice.

I am fulfilling my Google Assistant intents via an Express app.  I would like for users of my action to be able to get and modify data from their Strava account.  Strava supports Google Authentication and I wondered if I could use node libraries such as Passport (https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-strava-oauth2) to allow users to sign in to their strava account so that my action can make calls for their data?

I have a welcome intent that gets some Google profile data so wondering if I can pass through some details from this response?

```
googleApp.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => { 
  conv.ask(new Permission({
    context: 'Hi, can I  get your details from your Google account?',
    permissions: 'NAME'
  }));  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but probably not in the way you're looking at.

The `Permission` helper requests access to specific types of information - name and location. You're looking to establish more of an identity relationship (using their email address or Google account).

You can do this using [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/).

If you're sure you're using Google Sign In on the Strava side then things are even easier and you can take advantage of [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in). With this, once they sign in, your Action will get an Identity Token which you can use to get information including their Google ID and the email address associated with the signed-in Google account. They only need to sign-in once - afterwards, you'll be given an Identity Token whenever they connect.

If your Strava project and your Action are both using the same Google Cloud Project, things get even easier for your users. Once they have signed in on either client, [they're signed in on the other one](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth). So you'll know who they are immediately through the Identity Token.

Comment: many thanks @Prisoner, that Sign In for Assistant works exactly as documented.  I get access to an object (next comment, not real details).  Am I then able to access account info for services that implement Google Sign In (e.g. Strava), or do I need to have another step to explicitly sign in to Strava?

Comment: : {
  iss: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  nbf: 155898657760,
  aud: '397558759346-qdr3pufk60c2t2smdfdbapu8jb0egt0i4.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  sub: '111799074877916982344',
  email: 'jinky32@gmail.com',
  email_verified: true,
  name: 'Stuart Brown',
  picture: 'https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-p4GX0kkhp9kQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/DWCPuP1SBIA/s46-c/photo.jpg',
  given_name: 'Stuart',
  family_name: 'Brown',
  iat: 1228911050,
  exp: 13458000480,
  jti: '3b3363k345e0affcd97972d52189de82e3d21446'
}